# EditText, ListView and Button issue

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-edittext

I have an Android activity with an EditText, two buttons (Añadir and Aceptar) and a ListView. When I tip something in the EditText, I want to add it to the ListView when I push "Añadir". It works fine, but the problem is that when the EditText gains focus, the buttons become displaced.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7bfP.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBqdC.png

When I don't put the ListView, everything works fine. I've found this answer ([ListView with EditText Keyboard Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261436/listview-with-edittext-keyboard-issues)) to the problem, but I have to use a ListView since its content will be changed dynamically.

Code of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".AsistenteNombreActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:text="@string/que_deseas_buscar"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
        android:singleLine="true" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAceptar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonAnnadir"
        android:text="@string/aceptar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAnnadir"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/annadir" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonAceptar"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonAnnadir"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: how about android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your activity declaration on the manifest, try to add this attribute :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: try `adjustPan` instead of `adjustResize`

Comment: you're welcome, accept the answer by checking the green check mark in the left , so others can find it as useful answer.